# Is there a way to use a function to determine Add-Member value?

Tags: powershell

```
$thisplan = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $thisplan -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PlanID -Value $planid
Add-Member -InputObject $thisplan -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PlanName -Value $plan.name            
Add-Member -InputObject $thisplan -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SessionPassword -Value $sessionpass

 $schedule = $plan.backupConfiguration.advanceSchedule.periodSchedule 
    #DAY
     add-Member -InputObject $thisplan -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DayRetention -Value $schedule.daySchedule.retentionCount
      if ($schedule.daySchedule.retentionCount -gt 0)
      {
        $dstart = udptime($schedule.daySchedule.dayTime)
      }
      else
      {
        $dstart = ""
      }
      Add-Member -InputObject $thisplan -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DayStart -Value $dstart
########################
```

is there a way to make a function from the #day section?
This is a small part from my script.

Comment: Change `-MemberType` to `ScriptMethod` and make a scriptblock the `-Value`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 i changed all -MemberType to ScriptMethod but i dont understand "scriptblock the -value"

Comment: `$thisplan | Add-member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name etc -Value { if (so and so) { } else { } }`